# Isekai manga where the main character is summoned to a facility and forced to fight another person who was also summoned, he wins and escapes

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Manga where the MC gets summoned in a facility but is later forced to fight someone. Once he killed the person and realized it was also someone who got summoned like him he swore to escape the facility and destroy it.

After a kind of time skip he starts escaping but meets someone who works for the facility (I think it was a female) and easily gets beaten but was able to escape. He gets rescued by someone (I think it was a fairy) who he becomes friends with then they both decide to become allies.

Comment: Do you remember roughly when you read this? You might also want to check out [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) on what to include. If you have anything else to add be sure to [edit] it into the question.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for *Kuro no Mao*

> The Protagonist Kurono was summoned from Japan one day from his club room to another world. Upon being summoned he was controlled via a ring that rested on his head, this ring would bring him pain if he attempted to go against his summoners. He was subjected to intense experiments that destroyed and rebuilt his body over and over again until he eventually gained control over Black Magic. He was then forced to fight to the death against monsters and other captured subjects of the experiments. This was all seen as humane in the eyes of the people who captured him because he was considered nothing more than a monster anyway.
>
> This eventually broke him down to the point where he ceased to be Kurono Mao and was simply Subject No. 49. Thankfully he came to his senses at an opportune time and was able to escape from his captors.

During his escape, he encounters the female you were speaking of that easily beat him.

[image]